# imap not allowing use of gmail folders - mail.select folder other than 'inbox'

Tags: python, email, gmail, imap

Basically as stated in the title, I'm using

```
mail.select("inbox")
result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
ids = data[0] # data is a list.
id_list = ids.split() # ids is a space separated string
latest_email_id = id_list[-1] # get the latest
```

To get the most recent email from the inbox. Theoretically you can change 'inbox' to another label or folder in gmail (my labels and folders showed up using mail.list() just fine). I want to use my label "Server Status/Leviathan" but it throws the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\False Apparition\Desktop\test3.py", line 18, in <module>
    mail.select("Server Status/Leviathan")
  File "C:\Users\Ancient Abysswalker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 737, in select
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox)
  File "C:\Users\Ancient Abysswalker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1188, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Users\Ancient Abysswalker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1019, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: SELECT command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']
```

Which is different than if the label doesn't exist on gmail...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\False Apparition\Desktop\test3.py", line 20, in <module>
    result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
  File "C:\Users\Ancient Abysswalker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 715, in search
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, *criteria)
  File "C:\Users\Ancient Abysswalker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1188, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Users\Ancient Abysswalker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 936, in _command
    ', '.join(Commands[name])))
imaplib.error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED
```

Am I missing something? A library perhaps?

Comment: Can you use slashes in server statuses? Won't that conflict with the hierarchy separator?

Comment: Also, doing SEARCH ALL in order to retrieve one UID is O(wrong).

Comment: If your folder name has quotes or special characters, be sure to quote it; imaplib does not do this for you.

Comment: It appears that the whitespace is the problem that makes it unable to parse the command... Using mail.select("Server/Leviathan") works. Any idea why whitespace isn't allowed or how to get around it? Also why is result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL") wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add quotes around your folder name. Imaplib should do this for you, but it doesn't: `mail.select('"folder with space"')`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I would never have assumed that was the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: If this helps, please up vote and accept the answer.